# Is it possible to vary the return type annotation of a function based on its input value?

Tags: function, types, rust

I'd like to have a function that takes in a length argument, and returns an array that has that length:

```
fn make_zeros(length: &i16) -> [f64; length] {
    return [0; length]
}
```

Is there a rustic way of doing this, or should I just use a `Vec`?

Comment: The closest type you can return as of now is a `Box<[f64]>`, FWIW.

Comment: @Veedrac: … which you should practically always use `Vec<f64>` in favour of.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan If you don't need to change its length, what advantage does `Vec` have?

Comment: @Veedrac: it’s purely the convenience of consistency. `Box<[T]>` is practically never used.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I don't get why consistency is an argument - `Box<[T]>` is just an owned slice. The semantics you get from it (the lack of length-altering methods) is enough reason to prefer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types cannot at present be generic over numbers, which that would require. It is generally expected that something along those lines will happen at some point, but there is no schedule for it.

Your example would end up something like this:

```
fn make_zeroes<N: usize>() -> [f64; N] {
    return [0; N]
}
```

Note that this would be requiring constants; it’s never going to be possible to do it with anything other constants—a type must be known at compile time.

Comment: So you would call this by doing something like `make_zeroes<3>()`?

Comment: That hypothetical future code could be called as `make_zeroes::<3>()`. Or `make_zeroes(): [f64; 3]`, *&c.*

Answer (score 2):

You can of course use macros to provide versions of your function for statically known lengths. Look at the [arrayref](https://github.com/droundy/arrayref) crate for some macros with a similar scheme.